# javascript transform on interval wont work

Tags: javascript, html, css

Basically trying to create a game in which the user has to click a specific word which is layed out at the top of the page, I need to program 4 button html elements to bounce around inside a div container however, my html transform on interval is not working.

```js
var upperLimitY = 360;
var lowerLimitY = 0;
var upperLimitX = 520;
var lowerLimitX = 0;
var upperVelocity = 10;
var lowerVelocity = 2;
var velocity = 5;

var wordStore = document.getElementsByClassName("word1")[0];


function startGame() {
  setInterval(moveWord, 10);
}


function moveWord() {

  if (lowerLimitX < wordStore.style.transform.x < upperLimitX && lowerLimitY <
    wordStore.style.transform.y < upperLimitY) {

    wordStore.style.transform = "translate(" + velocity + "px ," + velocity + ")";
    velocity += velocity;
  } else {
    velocity *= -1;
  }
};
```

```html
<div class="wordGameContainerHeader">
  <h1>Word Wizard</h1>
  <h4>WORD TO FIND</h4>
</div>

<div class="wordGameContainer">
  <button class="word1">WORD 1</button>
  <button class="word2">WORD 2</button>
  <button class="word3">WORD 3</button>
  <button class="word4">WORD 4</button>
</div>

<div>
  <button onclick="startGame()" class="playButton">PLAY</button>
</div>
```

The buttons are embedded in a div with a size of 600px x 300px and the elements have a width of 80px and height of 40px and thus that is why I have the upper limit x to 600px - 80px and vise versa for the y limits. The button im testing the code on isn't moving at all.

Comment: Probably because there is no `style.transform.x`. Also your condition will not work out.

Answer (score 0):

You've missed writing `px` in the second parameter in the `moveWord` function. I've set 1s in the `setInterval` function to translate the word in slow motion so that you can see that the word is translating. That's it.

**Note:** I've just checked why your transform is not working. I didn't check anything else.

```js
function startGame() {
  setInterval(moveWord, 1000); // use 1s for translating slow.
}

function moveWord() {

  if (lowerLimitX < wordStore.style.transform.x < upperLimitX && lowerLimitY <
    wordStore.style.transform.y < upperLimitY) {

    wordStore.style.transform = "translate(" + velocity + "px ," + velocity + "px)";
    velocity += velocity;
  } else {
    velocity *= -1;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

### Syntax issues:

- `style.transform` has no sub properties (x and y).

You would have to parse it yourself using split  or regex.

- There was a `px` missing at the y part of translate, which made it invalid

`wordStore.style.transform = "translate(" + velocity + "px ," + velocity + "px)";`

- The chained condition logic `(x < y < z)` is not valid in javascript

`x < y && y < z`

### Logical issues:

- With your current logic, the buttons would bounce back on forth the same predefined line
- Once the buttons are out of bounds, your movements would stop, since you never add any value to the actual position after reversing `velocity`
- You would use the `class` like an `id`, which is okay but silly

### Commented example based on your code:

**Note: Run in full page mode**

```js
var upperVelocity = 10;
var lowerVelocity = 2;
//var velocity = 5; //REM: Dropped to bring some random dynamic into it
var speed = 25; //REM: Interval-Timeout
var bounds = null;

//REM: Calculating the bounds according to the bounds of .wordGameContainer
//var upperLimitY = 360;
//var lowerLimitY = 0;
//var upperLimitX = 520;
//var lowerLimitX = 0;

//REM: Not required, since there is only one "word1"
//var wordStore = document.getElementsByClassName("word1")[0];

function startGame(){
  //REM: Calculating the bounds
  bounds = document.querySelector(".wordGameContainer").getBoundingClientRect();

  //REM: Getting all .words
  var tListOfWords = document.getElementsByClassName("word");
  for(var i=0, j=tListOfWords.length; i<j; i++){
    //REM: Clearing the current timeout, else speeds up on pressing again
    clearInterval(tListOfWords[i].dataset.Interval);
  
    //REM: x and y require different directions, else they just keep bouncing back and forth diagonally
    tListOfWords[i].dataset.Direction = JSON.stringify({x: 1, y: 1});
  
    //REM: Storing the return of setInterval() to clear it eventually
    //REM: Binding the element instead, so that moveWord() can be used for all words the same
    tListOfWords[i].dataset.Interval = setInterval(moveWord.bind(null, tListOfWords[i]), speed);
    
    //REM: Adding event to stop the movement
    //REM: Using onmouseup to omit keyboard input (tab + enter)
    tListOfWords[i].onmouseup = function(){
      clearInterval(this.dataset.Interval);
      alert(this.id)
    }
  }
};

//REM: The .word not gets passed as parameter "element"
function moveWord(element){
  //REM: style.transform has no sub properties
  //REM: Using getBoundingClientRect() so the buttons entirely stay inside the box
  var tPosition = element.getBoundingClientRect(),
      tDirection = JSON.parse(element.dataset.Direction);

  //REM Calculate the movement according to upperVelocity and lowerVelocity
  //REM: Using different velocities for x, y to make less predictable and more dynamic
  var tMovementX = Math.floor(Math.random() * (upperVelocity - lowerVelocity) + lowerVelocity),
      tMovementY = Math.floor(Math.random() * (upperVelocity - lowerVelocity) + lowerVelocity);

  //REM: Adding the direction of the element
  tMovementX *= tDirection.x;
  tMovementY *= tDirection.y;

  //REM: Checking x
  if(
    (tPosition.left + tMovementX) <= bounds.left || 
    (tPosition.right + tMovementX) >= bounds.right
  ){
    tDirection.x *= -1;
    tMovementX *= -1;
    
    //REM: Storing the changed direction
    element.dataset.Direction = JSON.stringify(tDirection)
  };
  
  //REM: Checking y
  if(
    (tPosition.top + tMovementY) <= bounds.top ||
    (tPosition.bottom + tMovementY) >= bounds.bottom
  ){
    tDirection.y *= -1;
    tMovementY *= -1;
    
    //REM: Storing the changed direction
    element.dataset.Direction = JSON.stringify(tDirection)
  };

  //REM: Getting the actual left/top assigned to the style
  //REM: Note that those are not the same values as tPosition.
  var tLeftInsideParent = (parseFloat(element.style.left) || 0),
      tTopInsideParent = (parseFloat(element.style.top) || 0);

  element.style.left = tLeftInsideParent + tMovementX + "px";
  element.style.top = tTopInsideParent + tMovementY + "px"
};

//REM: Adjusting the bounds on scrolling and resizing
window.onscroll = window.onresize = function(){
  //REM: Calculating the bounds
  bounds = document.querySelector(".wordGameContainer").getBoundingClientRect()
};
```

```css
.word{
  position: relative
}

.wordGameContainer{
  background: #1390ff;
  height: 150px;
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wordGameContainerHeader">
  <h1>Word Wizard</h1>
  <h4>WORD TO FIND</h4>
</div>

<div>
  <button onclick="startGame()" class="playButton">PLAY</button>
</div>

<div class="wordGameContainer">
  <!--REM: Why is the "class" used like an "id"? -->
  <button id="word1" class="word">WORD 1</button>
  <button id="word2" class="word">WORD 2</button>
  <button id="word3" class="word">WORD 3</button>
  <button id="word4" class="word">WORD 4</button>
</div>

Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling..
```

Comment: Would there be any way to get it so the buttons don't exit the container?

Comment: The buttons do not exit the container in my browsers (latest of either Chrome, FFox, Edge). Which one are you using? Also note that it only runs correctly if you put the snippet in **Full Page Mode**.

Comment: Changed it to calculate the bounds on starting a game. Should work in the small snippet as well now.

Comment: honestly this is amazing lain cheers, IM HAVING ONE PROBLEM THOUGH :/ when i scroll down on my page the words start to bounce outside the container :/ it works perfect until I scroll? Btw sorry for the long reply I've been willing to get back to this but I was finding it daunting

Comment: @Java Lava: Probably the bounds are getting messed up. I can take a look, but not tonight anymore I assume.

Comment: Thats fine and thanks a ton! I was also wondering if I can make them move in a more linear fashion rather than sort of like a jiggling motion... But like any help is appreciated, more worried about the bounds

Comment: @Java Lava: Looks like all you gotta do is recalculate the bounds on scrolling. Added it at the end of my code.